# How do I work out a rug curl?

Tags: carpet

We recently moved into a place with a lot of hardwood floors and so we needed to put down about 5 area rugs. A lot them arrived rolled up and we unrolled them there was lingering curl that we needed to more or less press out.

It's been a couple months now and two carpets still have curl remaining in one corner that doesn't seem to want to settle. At this point, I've tried placing books on the curl for a couple days, folding the curl under itself to try and force it out, and of course just giving it time to work out but it doesn't seem to want to go away.

If it matters, the others which did settle out seem to vary a lot. One has a heavy pile, the other two have a very thin pile.

Is there anything else I should be thinking about or trying to get the curl to work out?

Comment: Heat or moisture. Depends on what the rugs are made of.

Comment: I think they're polyester weaves, but I'm not sure. Can you expand into an answer?

Comment: place them upside down, walk on the ripples, and let sit for a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synthetics tend to soften nicely with a little heat. If you're in a warm climate, lay them face down on a clean surface in the sun for a while. They should become noticeably more limp. Bring them inside while still warm and lay them out.

If you don't have warm sunshine, a heat lamp or other mild heat source could do. Be careful not to melt anything.

Natural fibers tend to relax with moisture. A clothing steamer or simple spray bottom might be enough.

Comment: This worked great. Little bit of crispness on the carpet, but it's not super noticeable. Thanks for the tip!